# .htaccess redirect individual query string to specific url

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Help much appreciated - i am extending my understanding of .htaccess but am having real trouble here. The situation is:

```
    /people.php forwards to /people
```

I want to forward

```
    /people.php?id=1 to /people/james-doe
    /people.php?id=32 to /people/lucy-brown
```

and so on -

but unsurprisingly what i get is:

```
    /people/id=1
```

Now I am sure there is an elegant solution to this - can anyone offer any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^people\.php$ /people/james-doe? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=32(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^people\.php$ /people/lucy-brown? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Perfect - works great. If I wanted to add other variables to the initial string such as id=&gid=3#69 what is the best practice for notation?

Comment: In that case you can use: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=1&gid=[^&]+(&|$) [NC]` condition

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: i am struggling here - learning on my feet. How do i specify the values of the numbers before and after the #?